# Angular 5 percent pipe digitInfo not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

If I do this in an Angular 5 template:

```
{{0.7 | percent:'1.2-5'}}
```

I get this as expected: `70.00%`

However, when I do this:

```
{{0.07 | percent:'1.2-5'}}
```

I get `7.00000%` instead of what the expected `7.00%`

Am I just doing something wrong or is this a bug in Angular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like a bug with [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) because [PercentPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe) uses it for formatting. Simple removal of `maxFractionDigits` which is the maximum number of digits after fraction (default is `3`) will get you the desired result:

```
{{0.7 | percent:'1.2'}} --> 70.00%
{{0.07 | percent:'1.2'}} --> 7.00%
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, that doesn't help me as I do need to ensure a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 5 fraction digits. Perhaps I'll have to write my own filter on top of angular's till this is fixed?

Comment: Please log an github issue, so community is aware of this bug.